# XSLT - IP Address Range Subtracted to find # of Hosts

Tags: xml, xslt

so I have two IP address, an endIP and startIP. The number of hosts must be calculated from the range of the IP addresses.

I tested an example that the start IP address would be 192.168.2.188 with 88 hosts. So I was given the end address as 192.168.3.19. However, with no record of the 88 hosts in my xml file (since it is automatically generated), how am I suppose to find the number of hosts?

So I did a `<xsl:value-of select="endIP - startIP"/>` thinking it would give me the remainder at the very least. However, that returned a "NaN" after I parsed it. Go figure, since it's multiple decimals. I'm not extremely familiar with XSL, so this is creating quite a headache.

I am completely stumped on how to figure the host number based on an IP address range. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using XSLT 1 or 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is to convert the ip code into an integer and then do the substraction. This, of course, makes some implicit assumptions about the number of hosts in sub nets.

For this input file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<HOSTS>
  <HOST ID="a" IP="192.168.2.188"/>
  <HOST ID="b" IP="192.168.3.19"/>
</HOSTS>
```

you could use the following XSLT file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template name="ip_to_number">
    <xsl:param name="ip"/>
    <xsl:variable name="ip1" select="substring-before($ip, '.')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="ip2" select="substring-before(substring-after($ip, concat($ip1, '.')), '.')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="ip3" select="substring-before(substring-after($ip, concat($ip1, '.', $ip2, '.')), '.')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="ip4" select="substring-after($ip, concat($ip1, '.', $ip2, '.', $ip3, '.'))"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="(((number($ip1) * 256) + number($ip2)) * 256 + number($ip3)) * 256 + number($ip4)"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/HOSTS">

    <xsl:variable name="number_a">
      <xsl:call-template name="ip_to_number">
        <xsl:with-param name="ip"><xsl:value-of select="HOST[@ID='a']/@IP"/></xsl:with-param>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="number_b">
      <xsl:call-template name="ip_to_number">
        <xsl:with-param name="ip"><xsl:value-of select="HOST[@ID='b']/@IP"/></xsl:with-param>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:text>Number of hosts: </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$number_b - $number_a + 1"/>

  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result is:

```
Number of hosts: 88
```

You could write another helper template which computes the difference between the two ip numbers. Also you may want to change the templates in such a way that they extract the ip numbers directly from the source document instead of passing them as parameters.

Answer (score 2):

**This input XML file of sample ranges of IP numbers:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<IPRanges>
  <IPRange start="192.168.2.188" end="192.168.3.19"/>
  <IPRange start="0.0.0.0" end="0.0.0.0"/>
  <IPRange start="0.0.0.1" end="0.0.0.0"/>
  <IPRange start="0.0.0.0" end="0.0.0.1"/>
  <IPRange start="0.0.0.0" end="1.1.1.1"/>
  <IPRange start="0.0.0.1" end="1.0.0.0"/>
  <IPRange start="0.0.0.0" end="255.255.255.255"/>
  <IPRange start="4.3.2.1" end="8.7.6.5"/>
  <IPRange start="0.0.1.0" end="0.0.0.1"/>
</IPRanges>
```

**Given as test input to this XSLT transformation:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" />

  <xsl:template name="CalcIpToDecimal">
    <xsl:param name="ip"/>
    <xsl:param name="pv"/>
    <xsl:variable name="ipCar" select="substring-before($ip, '.')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="ipCdr" select="substring-after($ip, '.')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="pvCar" select="substring-before($pv, '.')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="pvCdr" select="substring-after($pv, '.')"/>

    <xsl:variable name="valCar" select="$ipCar * $pvCar"/>
    <xsl:variable name="valCdr">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$ipCdr eq ''">0</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:call-template name="CalcIpToDecimal">
            <xsl:with-param name="ip" select="$ipCdr"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="pv" select="$pvCdr"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="$valCar + $valCdr"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="IpToDecimal">
    <xsl:param name="ip"/>
    <xsl:call-template name="CalcIpToDecimal">
      <xsl:with-param name="ip" select="concat($ip, '.')"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="pv" select="'16777216.65536.256.1.'"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="HostCountInIPRange">
    <xsl:param name="start"/>
    <xsl:param name="end"/>
    <xsl:variable name="startDecimal">
      <xsl:call-template name="IpToDecimal">
        <xsl:with-param name="ip" select="$start"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="endDecimal">
      <xsl:call-template name="IpToDecimal">
        <xsl:with-param name="ip" select="$end"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="diff" select="$endDecimal - $startDecimal"/>
    <xsl:variable name="absDiff"
                  select="$diff*($diff >=0) - $diff*($diff &lt; 0)"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$absDiff + 1"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/IPRanges/IPRange">
    <xsl:text>In the range of </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="@end"/>
    <xsl:text> to </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="@start"/>
    <xsl:text> there are </xsl:text>
    <xsl:call-template name="HostCountInIPRange">
      <xsl:with-param name="start" select="@start"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="end" select="@end"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
    <xsl:text> hosts.</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Yields this output demonstrating the number of unique host numbers that exist in the given ranges:**

```
  In the range of 192.168.3.19 to 192.168.2.188 there are 88 hosts.
  In the range of 0.0.0.0 to 0.0.0.0 there are 1 hosts.
  In the range of 0.0.0.0 to 0.0.0.1 there are 2 hosts.
  In the range of 0.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0 there are 2 hosts.
  In the range of 1.1.1.1 to 0.0.0.0 there are 1.684301E7 hosts.
  In the range of 1.0.0.0 to 0.0.0.1 there are 1.6777216E7 hosts.
  In the range of 255.255.255.255 to 0.0.0.0 there are 4.294967296E9 hosts.
  In the range of 8.7.6.5 to 4.3.2.1 there are 6.7372037E7 hosts.
  In the range of 0.0.0.1 to 0.0.1.0 there are 256 hosts.
```